# How to get column value from previous row for each group?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'll try to explain the problem right:

I have a table like this:

```
Table: stg_mov_salida

id_movement | id_product | id_warehouse | movement_date | id_sale | sale_value | ...
209338          54545          2          "2011-05-21"    163299     75.95
209306          54545          2          "2011-06-05"    163267     75.95
209347          54545          2          "2012-10-26"    163308     77.95
209399          54545          3          "2011-01-22"    163360     79.95
209302          54545          3          "2011-01-23"    163263     72.95
209304          54545          3          "2011-01-24"    163265     72.95
```

And I want to get the `sale_value` of the previous row, but only if the previous row belongs to the same `id_product` and `id_warehouse` that the current row.

The table `stg_mov_salida` is a staging table ordered by:

```
 id_product asc, id_warehouse asc, movement_date asc
```

As I've read on other questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196190/mysql-subtracting-value-from-previous-row-group-by) or similar), I've tried to do it without success. The last query (and the closest to my solution) I've tried is this:

```
SELECT x2.*,
   (SELECT x2.sale_value AS last_sale_value
            FROM stg_mov_salida ms 
                WHERE x2.id_product = ms.id_product 
                AND x2.id_warehouse = ms.id_warehouse
                AND x2.date_movement  > ms.date_movement 
            ORDER BY ms.id_product asc, 
                             ms.id_warehouse asc, 
                             ms.date_movement asc
            LIMIT 1)
FROM stg_mov_salida x2
```

But this query is so slow that I've never seen it finishing, even for only one given `id_product`, therefore if this query is correct, I can't use it because is too slow.

Anyone knows how to solve my problem?

**UPDATE:**

**Expected result:**

```
id_movement | id_product | id_ware | mov_date | id_sale | sale_value | prev_sale_value
  209338       54545          2    "2011-05-21"  163299     75.95           null
  209306       54545          2    "2011-06-05"  163267     75.95           75.95
  209347       54545          2    "2012-10-26"  163308     77.95           75.95
  209399       54545          3    "2011-01-22"  163360     79.95           null
  209302       54545          3    "2011-01-23"  163263     72.95           79.95
  209304       54545          3    "2011-01-24"  163265     72.95           72.95
```

The `null` values on `prev_sale_value` would be because that row is the first on the group of `(id_product, id_warehouse)`, but the idea is to replace that `null` with the `sale_value` of the same row directly, but I'll do it when I get the correct `prev_sale_value` for each row.

Any help would be appreciated

For easily response, here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ce21c/2)

I've tried this query too, but it doesn't works properly:

```
select x2.*,
lag(sale_value, 1) over (partition by sale_value
                                order by id_product asc,
                                id_warehouse asc,
                                date_movement asc) as last_sale_value

from stg_mov_salida x2
order by id_product asc, id_warehouse asc, date_movement asc
```

Comment: What is the expected output for the example table that you have given ?

Comment: Updated question with expected result. If you need additional info don't doubt to ask!

Comment: Check out the `lag()` function: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: I've tried using `lag()`, and it improves the execution time but using it I don't get the expected result yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `lag` is the right way to go, but your arguments are wrong. As you stated:

> I want to get the sale_value of the previous row, but only if the previous row belongs to the same id_product and id_warehouse that the current row.

This means that your `partiton by` clause should include `id_product` and `id_warehouse`:

```
select x2.*,
lag(sale_value, 1) over (partition by id_product asc, id_warehouse asc
                         order by date_movement asc) as last_sale_value    
from stg_mov_salida x2
order by id_product asc, id_warehouse asc, date_movement asc
```

Comment: Perfect! Only you should delete `sale_value` from `partition by` clause and it works perfectly! Correct it for future visitors ;) Thank you very much!

Comment: @carexcer arg, rigtht. Copy-paste bug - fixed. Thanks for noticing.