# Count occurrences that differ within a column

Tags: mysql

I want to be able to select the amount of times the data in columns Somedata_A and Somedata_B has changed from the from the previous row within its column. I've tried using `DISTINCT` and it works to some degree. `{1,2,3,2,1,1}` will show 3 when I want it to show 4 course there's 5 different values in sequence.

Example:

```
 A,B,C,D,E,F
{1,2,3,2,1,1}
```

`A`  compare to `B` gives a difference, `B` compare to `C` gives a difference . . . `E` compare to `F` gives not difference. All in all it gives 4 differences within a set of 6 values.

I have gotten `DISTINCT` to work but it does not really do the trick for me. And to add more to the question I'm really not interested it the whole range, lets say just the 2 last days/entries per Title.

Second I'm concern about performance issues. I tried the query below on a real set of data and it got interrupted probably due to timeout.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14849/2)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE testdata(
Title varchar(10),
Date varchar(10),
Somedata_A int(5),
Somedata_B int(5));


INSERT INTO testdata (Title, Date, Somedata_A, Somedata_B) VALUES
("Alpha", '123', 1, 2), 
("Alpha", '234', 2, 2), 
("Alpha", '345', 1, 2),
("Alpha", '349', 1, 2), 
("Alpha", '456', 1, 2), 
("Omega", '123', 1, 1), 
("Omega", '234', 2, 2), 
("Omega", '345', 3, 3),
("Omega", '349', 4, 3), 
("Omega", '456', 5, 4),
("Delta", '123', 1, 1), 
("Delta", '234', 2, 2), 
("Delta", '345', 1, 3),
("Delta", '349', 2, 3), 
("Delta", '456', 1, 4);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t.Title, (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Somedata_A) FROM testdata AS tt WHERE t.Title = tt.Title) AS A,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Somedata_B) FROM testdata AS tt WHERE t.Title = tt.Title) AS B
    FROM testdata AS t
    GROUP BY t.Title
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14849/2/0)**:

```
| TITLE | A | B |
|-------|---|---|
| Alpha | 2 | 1 |
| Delta | 2 | 4 |
| Omega | 5 | 4 |
```

Comment: You are right. Corrected the error.

Comment: Are the sequential records always 1 day apart like your example? (The answer becomes much easier if you can always JOIN to the following sequential record)

Comment: Well, the record will always be a new ID key apart so in a way its like they are 1 day apart.

Comment: There are two great examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196190/mysql-subtracting-value-from-previous-row-group-by) for doing row comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work: it uses a variable for row number, joins on an offset of 1 and then counts differences for A and B.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3bbc8/9/2

```
set @i = 0;
set @j = 0;

Select 
A.Title aTitle, 
sum(Case when A.SomeData_A <> B.SomeData_A then 1 else 0 end) AVar, 
sum(Case when A.SomeData_B <> B.SomeData_B then 1 else 0 end) BVar
from 
(SELECT Title, @i:=@i+1 as ROWID, SomeData_A, SomeData_B 
FROM testdata
ORDER BY Title, date desc) as A
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Title, @j:=@j+1 as ROWID, SomeData_A, SomeData_B
FROM testdata
ORDER BY Title, date desc) as B
 ON A.RowID= B.RowID + 1
 AND A.Title=B.Title
Group by A.Title
```

Answer (score 0):

This works (see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6ee6a/11)) (FYI: Your results in the question do not match your data - for instance, for Alpha, ColumnA: it never changes from 1. The answer should be 0)

Hopefully you can adapt this Statement to your actual data model

```
SELECT t1.title, SUM(t1.Somedata_A<>t2.Somedata_a) as SomeData_A
  ,SUM(t1.Somedata_b<>t2.Somedata_b) as SomeData_B
FROM testdata AS t1
JOIN testdata AS t2
  ON t1.title = t2.title
    AND t2.date = DATE_ADD(t1.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY t1.title
ORDER BY t1.title;
```

Comment: The result is based on the DISTINCT and it count that there is one occurrence of 1 in Column A. I want it to be zero but my best effort took me only so far as using DISTINCT.

Comment: Is it possible to get an example without the DATE_ADD function? I've updated the data to look more like the data I use.