# Positional based operation in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Id like to run a query that would be very easy to do using arrays in a imperative language using the array index. I have the following table:

```
value  id
10     x1
20     x2
15     x3
25     x4
30     x5
31     x6
```

I wish to calculate the difference of pair of vicinal values like:

```
value
20 - 10
25 - 15
31 - 30
```

I only know that x6>x5>...>x1. I have no clue on how to do this using MySQL.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196190/mysql-subtracting-value-from-previous-row-group-by

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a way of ordering your data you could generate row numbers and join the odd numbered rows to the even numbered rows

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(value int, id varchar(2));

insert into t values
(10   ,  'x1'),
(20   ,  'x2'),
(15   ,  'x3'),
(25   ,  'x4'),
(30   ,  'x5'),
(31   ,  'x6');

select s.*,a.*
from
(select id, value , 
         @rn:=@rn + 1 rn
from t
cross join (select @rn:=0) r
order by id
) a
join
(
select id, value , 
         @rn1:=@rn1 + 1 rn1
from t
cross join (select @rn1:=0) r
order by id
) s
on s.rn1 = rn + 1
where a.rn % 2 > 0
;
+------+-------+------+------+-------+------+
| id   | value | rn1  | id   | value | rn   |
+------+-------+------+------+-------+------+
| x2   |    20 |    2 | x1   |    10 |    1 |
| x4   |    25 |    4 | x3   |    15 |    3 |
| x6   |    31 |    6 | x5   |    30 |    5 |
+------+-------+------+------+-------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```